# Max value of a column based on every unique value of another column (Dataframe)

Tags: r, dataframe, max, unique

I'm trying to get the max value of y per unique value of id.

```
id <- c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2")
y <- c("2.43", "2.11", "2.31", "3.11", "2.12", "2.10")
output <- c("2.43", "2.43", "2.43", "3.11", "3.11", "3.11")

df <- data.frame(id, y, output)

  id    y output
1  1 2.43   2.43
2  1 2.11   2.43
3  1 2.31   2.43
4  2 3.11   3.11
5  2 2.12   3.11
6  2 2.10   3.11
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `group_by` 'id'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%   
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(output = max(y))
```

---

Or with `ave` from `base R`

```
df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
df$output <- with(df, ave(y, id, FUN = max))
```

Comment: Thank you so much @akrun !!